# Как подключиться к базе данных SQL?

Tags: java, sql, sql-server

Допустим, у меня есть база данных в MS SQL Server. Как можно к ней подключиться из Java (Eclipse)?

Comment: Для подключения к любой БД из Java через JDBC нужен JDBC Driver. Обычно его можно найти на сайте той БД которую ты используешь.

Answer (score 1):

Пример подключения к СУБД через JDBC.
Здесь используется MySQL, для MS SQL нужен просто другой JDBC-драйвер.

```
//STEP 1. Import required packages
import java.sql.*;

public class FirstExample {
   // JDBC driver name and database URL
   static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
   static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";

   //  Database credentials
   static final String USER = "username";
   static final String PASS = "password";

   public static void main(String[] args) {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;
   try{
      //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      //STEP 3: Open a connection
      System.out.println("Connecting to database...");
      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);

      //STEP 4: Execute a query
      System.out.println("Creating statement...");
      stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sql;
      sql = "SELECT id, first, last, age FROM Employees";
      ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

      //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
      while(rs.next()){
         //Retrieve by column name
         int id  = rs.getInt("id");
         int age = rs.getInt("age");
         String first = rs.getString("first");
         String last = rs.getString("last");

         //Display values
         System.out.print("ID: " + id);
         System.out.print(", Age: " + age);
         System.out.print(", First: " + first);
         System.out.println(", Last: " + last);
      }
      //STEP 6: Clean-up environment
      rs.close();
      stmt.close();
      conn.close();
   }catch(SQLException se){
      //Handle errors for JDBC
      se.printStackTrace();
   }catch(Exception e){
      //Handle errors for Class.forName
      e.printStackTrace();
   }finally{
      //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(stmt!=null)
            stmt.close();
      }catch(SQLException se2){
      }// nothing we can do
      try{
         if(conn!=null)
            conn.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try
   }//end try
   System.out.println("Goodbye!");
}//end main
}//end FirstExample
```

Источник:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-sample-code.htm

JDBC для MS SQL:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/aa937724.aspx

Comment: Все сделал, работает, спасибо)

Comment: @vasyasgors: На здоровье! Был очень рад помочь!!

Answer (score 1):

сейчас уже в моде java8, поэтому всё намного проще
(пример  использование хранимок)

```
static final String Base = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/EMP";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
ResultSet rs;
................
try (Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(Base, Base_login, Base_password);
     CallableStatement proc = con.prepareCall("{call xxxx(" + param + ")}");) {
        rs = proc.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
.................. 
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
       ................
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

подключаются не к файлам базы, а к серверу базы данных. если его нет (не установлен/не запущен), то никакой драйвер не поможет.

и почему 3 файла и что такое "MSQ", вы ничего там не напутали?

Comment: Есть такая БД, называет SQLite и вот в ней нет никакого сервера, есть только файлы, к которым и выполняется "подключение".

Comment: ТС писал про MS SQL

Comment: Можно предположить, что "MSQ" это какая-то разновидность Lite БД. Хотя скорее всего он просто описался или не очень понимает о чём спрашивает.

Comment: +1 вполне возможно, что ТС запутался. хотелось бы уточнений от него

Comment: я имел в виду microsoft sql server management studio